# Get JSON Web Token payload data within controller action

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm implementing JWT based authorization for my ASP.NET Web API application with Angular2 SPA. All is well and clear regarding authorization flow except for one detail. I am wondering how to get JWT payload information within the Web API controller action?

Looking through the web I can't find any solution that I would go for, for example, setting `Thread.Principal` or something like that.

What are the recommended ways to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal process to handle a JWT token as authentication in ASP.NET is:

1. Get the token from the request and ensure is valid.
2. Create a principal based on the information contained within the token and associate it with the request.

This implies that the payload information within the token is available through the request principal usually in the form of claims. For example, if your JWT contains information about the user roles it would get mapped to a role claim available in the principal.

You don't mention if you're using OWIN or not so I'll assume OWIN for the example, but it shouldn't really matter or be much different at the controller level.

Despite the fact you're concerned only with the data consumption part, if curious, you can read through this set of tutorials about ASP.NET Web API (OWIN) for a more in-depth look on the whole process:

- [Introduction](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin)
- [Authentication (HS256)](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin/01-authentication-rs256)
- [Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin/03-authorization)

The **last one would be the one with most interest** , you'll note the following code snippet on that one:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("claims")]
public object Claims()
{
    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    return claimsIdentity.Claims.Select(c =>
        new
        {
            Type = c.Type,
            Value = c.Value
        });
}
```

This relies on the [`User.Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.ApiController.User) available within the controller to list all the claims of the currently authenticated identity. Unless you have an authentication pipeline configured rather different then what it's the norm, these claims are mapped from the JWT payload your API receives.